# Compute the number of days to collect $n$ collectables when receiving one collectable each day with uniform distribution.

Tags: probability, expected-value, uniform-distribution, coupon-collector

Let $n$ different types of coupons. Jhon wishes to collect them all. Each day he receives one coupon with uniform distribution with complete independence between the days. Let $X$ be a random variable that marks the number of days until Jhon collected all coupons. Find the expected value of $X$.

---

I have written some proof, but there is one part where I'm not sure I'm executing the correct calculations. I'd love someone else to have a look.

---

First let $X_i$ be a random variable marking the number of days it took Jhon to collect the $i$ coupon after being the owner of $i-1$ coupons. Denote, $X = X_1+...+X_n$.

From the linear property we have: $$E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{n} E[X_i]$$

**This is the part I'm unsure about:**

Let us compute $E[X_i]$. Denote, $E[X_i]$ is the average number of days it took Jhon to draw one of $n-i+1$ coupon whilst receiving each day one of $n$ coupons with uniform distribution. If we think Jhon would be satisfied with each on the $n$ coupons then we would have $E[X_i] = {n \over 2}$ so since in this case we have ($n= n-i+1$) then $E[X_i] = {n-i+1 \over 2}$.

This leaves us with: $$E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^n {n-i+1 \over 2} = {1 \over 2}\sum_{i=1}^n(n+1)-{1 \over 2}\sum_{i=1}^ni=...={n(2n+3) \over 4}$$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coupon collector problem doubts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401561/coupon-collector-problem-doubts)

Comment: @EthanBolker i didn't know this was a known problem thank you! It would seem though that I didn't compute $E[X_i]$ correctly. Do you mind explaining what's my problem with it?

Comment: Not my area of expertise, so it would take some time for me to figure out your error. Perhaps someone else here will step in.

Comment: It is the **probability** of collecting a new coupon $p_i$,  that is $= \frac{n-i+1}{n}$ The  expected **time** to collect it would be its reciprocal, following the geometric distribution. Look it up here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem